# Grails upgrade from 1.0.5 to 2.4.4

Tags: grails

I have a collection of applications written in Grails v1.0.5. The application does work flawlessly. But, I'm looking into the possibility of upgrading to the latest version(2.4.4). I know it is quite a huge leap starting from 1.0.5 but any pointers on where to start?
Official site holds documentation only from 1.2.0(makes me feel like I'm in old age).
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I had to do something simillar and the main problem was the changes in the plugins I used (most of them were deprecated like Acegi and does not work in grails 2.x, i had to move to Spring Security Core Plugin), I had to refactor many classes and gps. In my case I started updating to 1.3.x and then to 2.x if you jump too many versions at a time is hard to know what is failing...

Comment: if 2.4.4 is causing too much of a headache, will upgrade to 1.3.x and proceed! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The safest way to upgrade an application from 1.x to 2.x would be to create an empty 2.x project, then slowly, by hand, move the following:

1. Contents of application.properties into `BuildConfig.groovy` (e.g. install plugins).
2. Contents of `Config.groovy` and `Resources.groovy` (do this by hand not by copying the file)
3. Tests (copy files)
4. Domain classes (copy files)
5. Controllers (copy files)
6. Services (copy files)
7. Filters (copy files)
8. `URLMappings.groovy` (by hand not by copying the file)

Depending on the size of the applications and complexity this could be very quick, or very painful. One thing to stress. **Test, Test, Test**.

Comment: Too bad! would love to upvote! Thanks ! Now, I have a place to start!