# Why "HTTP ERROR: 503 SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE" even though Grails-1.0.5's run-app executed successfully?

Tags: grails

I have an application running on **Grails 1.0.5, Java 1.6, IDE Intellij Idea 15**.  Wherever I execute a *rup-app* command to launch application, it executed successfully. Following is log of application start-up -

> Welcome to Grails 1.0.5 - http ://grails.org/ Licensed under Apache
>   Standard License 2.0 Grails home is set to: C:\grails-1.0.5                Base
>   Directory: C:\GitWorkSpace\bruce_kpi_dashboard Running script
>   C:\grails-1.0.5\scripts\RunApp.groovy Environment set to development
>
> Loading with installed plug-ins: ["blurb", "richui", "navigation",
>   "quartz"] ...
>        [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Users\mdn2836.grails\1.0.5\projects\bruce_kpi_dashboard Running
>   Grails application.. [0] commons.DefaultGrailsApplication The class
>   [resources] was not found when attempting to load Grails application.
>   Skipping.   [8491] spring.GrailsWebApplicationContext Refreshing
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsWebApplicationContext@330345ed:
>   display name
>   [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsWebApplicationContext@330345ed];
>   startup date [Mon Mar 21 12:38:00 IST 2016]; parent:
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@3c0f3387
>   [8491] spring.GrailsWebApplicationContext Bean factory for application
>   context
>   [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsWebApplicationContext@330345ed]:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@696911f6
>
> Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/dashboard

While I launch application with URI http ://localhost:8080/dashboard,

I got response ---

[image]

I am novice in Grails 1.0.5 and I am not able to find the documentation as well because it is discontinued. Please help me to run my application as I have been stuck here since last two days and my development work has been stalled due to it.

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Grails 1.0.5 is trully old version. Did you try to update your project to newer distribution? Here you can find a tutorial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29163287/grails-upgrade-from-1-0-5-to-2-4-4

Comment: @MichalSzulc I can't update it. This is the requirement of company as of now. I have to work on this version only